# How do I declare a var variable with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've got the following piece of code, but I can't find how to get the var `TypeSyntax`. 
Any ideas?

```
Syntax.LocalDeclarationStatement(                   
    declaration: Syntax.VariableDeclaration(
        type: Syntax.PredefinedType(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.VarKeyword)),
        variables: Syntax.SeparatedList(
        Syntax.VariableDeclarator(
            identifier: Syntax.Identifier(name)))
        )
    )
);
```

this fails with an Argument exception that says: "keyword"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'd use:

```
Syntax.LocalDeclarationStatement(
    declaration: Syntax.VariableDeclaration(
        type: Syntax.IdentifierName(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.VarKeyword)),
        variables: Syntax.SeparatedList(new[] { 
            Syntax.VariableDeclarator(
                identifier: Syntax.Identifier(name)) })));
```

Comment: Yep, the issue is that that at isn't actually a keyword, its what we call a contextual keyword.

Answer (score 19):

Jb Evain's answer is correct; I just thought that I would add that the reason for the error is because "var" is not a *predefined type*. A predefined type is something like "int" or "string".

The *syntactic* analyzer does not know whether or not you have a class named "var" in scope; "var" is treated not as a predefined type, but rather as just another name for just another type. Only if we cannot find a type in scope named "var" does the *semantic* analyzer then decide, oh, this must be an implicitly typed local.

The reason for this is because "var" was added in C# 3, and there might be C# 1 or 2 programs that use "var" as the name of a type. We did not want to break those programs.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Eric, it makes sense now. I think I got lost because I didn't realize that IdentifierNameSyntax is a TypeSyntax and  I was missing a bit of context

Answer (score 7):

Not a precise answer to your question, but another (and simpler) way to achieve the same affect would be to use Syntax.ParseStatement:

```
Syntax.ParseStatement("var " + name);
```

Comment: +1 Much more "declarative". I vote to add _code quotations_ to C#, with interpolation. Something like this in Nemerle: `<| var $name; |>`.

Answer (score 4):

To simplify answering questions like these, I've written a tool called Quoter that can generate syntax tree API calls for any given C# program:

https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net