# Roslyn Rename variable const in Majusucle

Tags: c#, roslyn, diagnostics

Trying to convert that:

```
const string maj = "variable";
```

in

```
const string MAJ = "variable";
```

I'm using a Diagnostic with CodeFix.

I've already done the Diagnostic:

```
var localDeclarationConst = node as LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax;
if (localDeclarationConst != null &&
    localDeclarationConst.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)
    )
{
    foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable in localDeclarationConst.Declaration.Variables)
    {
        var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable);
        if (symbol != null)
        {
            string varName = symbol.Name;
            if (!varName.Equals(varName.ToUpper()))
            {
                addDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, localDeclarationConst.GetLocation(), "Les constantes doivent être en majusucle"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But I cannot find a way for the CodeFix. Here is what I already wrote:

```
if (token.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword))
{
    var ConstClause = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)token.Parent;
    var test = ConstClause.GetText();
    var newConstClause = ConstClause.With //What with this With ??


    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(ConstClause, newConstClause);

    return new[] { CodeAction.Create("Mettre en maj", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)) };
}
```

As you can see, I'm looking for something that I can use with the .With

**Edit:**

So, I begin to understand how it works. But there is a point that I cannot know how it works. Let me explain:

```
if (token.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword))
{
   var ConstClause = (VariableDeclaratorSyntax)token.Parent;
   var test = ConstClause.Identifier.Text;
   var newConstClause = ConstClause.ReplaceToken(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(test), SyntaxFactory.Identifier(test.ToUpperInvariant()));
   var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(ConstClause, newConstClause);

   return new[] { CodeAction.Create("Make upper", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)) };


 }
```

Here it's what I've done. To acces to the name of the variable (ConstClause.Identifier.Text) I use a VariableDeclaratorSyntax instead of the LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax.

But it doesn't work. What does I have to use??
It will be very helpful, because I will know how to change the name of my variables. And I need that.

Comment: If you haven't already looked at the template for Code Fixes, you might want to. We show how to do a rename in a code fix that uses the actual rename API. That way, we'll update (smartly!) all uses of your constant, not just the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I'll find a way a now it works!
Here is the Diagnostic:

```
var localDeclarationConst = node as LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax;
if (localDeclarationConst != null &&
    localDeclarationConst.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword)
    )
{
foreach (VariableDeclaratorSyntax variable in localDeclarationConst.Declaration.Variables)
{
     string varName = variable.Identifier.Text;
     if (!varName.Equals(varName.ToUpper()))
     {
        addDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variable.GetLocation(), "Les constantes doivent être en majusucle"));
     }

}
```

And here is the CodeFix:

```
 var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken); (root)
 var token = root.FindToken(span.Start); 
 var node = root.FindNode(span);

 if (node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.VariableDeclarator))
 {
   if (token.IsKind(SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken))
   {
        var variable = (VariableDeclaratorSyntax)node;
        string newName = variable.Identifier.ValueText;
        string NameDone = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < newName.Length; i++)
        {
             NameDone = NameDone.ToString() + char.ToUpper(newName[i]);
        }

        var leading = variable.Identifier.LeadingTrivia;
        var trailing = variable.Identifier.TrailingTrivia;

        VariableDeclaratorSyntax newVariable = variable.WithIdentifier(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(leading, NameDone, trailing));

        var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(variable, newVariable);
        return new[] { CodeAction.Create("Make upper", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)) };
   }
}
```

If something looks wrong tell me, but I tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try `ReplaceToken()` instead of a With method.

Also, in your diagnostic, you could just use `VariableDeclarator.Identifier` instead of forcing the symbol to be created with `GetDeclaredSymbol`.

Comment: How do you use the ReplaceToken to put a text in capital?? Because that's my purpuse..

Comment: You need to create a new token with the text you want. ` Syntax. Identifier()` is the method for that.

Comment: Syntax seems to be good, and I have a look here, you answered too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400248/how-do-i-declare-a-var-variable-with-roslyn
But who do you use it? The name "Syntax" is not recognized by Visual Studio for me..

Comment: Oh, it's called SyntaxFactory now. Sorry.