# Rename multiple variables in 1 click

Tags: c#, rename, roslyn

I've made a CodeFix who rename a variable if its name doesn't correspond to some laws.
By exemple, "int" variable need to begin with an "i". I've made this CodeFix and it works:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CodeAction>> GetFixesAsync(Document document, TextSpan 
span, IEnumerable<Diagnostic> diagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken); 
  var token = root.FindToken(span.Start); 
  var node = root.FindNode(span);

  if (node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.VariableDeclarator))
  {
     if (node.Parent.Parent is LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)
     {
       var Verify = (LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax)node.Parent.Parent;
       var Verify2 = (VariableDeclarationSyntax)node.Parent;
       if (!Verify.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword))
       {
          if (Verify2.Type.ToString() == "int")
          {
            if (token.IsKind(SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken))
            {
                var variable = (VariableDeclaratorSyntax)node;
                string newName = variable.Identifier.ValueText;
                if (newName.Length > 1)
                {
                  newName = char.ToUpper(newName[0]) + newName.Substring(1);
                }
                var leading = variable.Identifier.LeadingTrivia;
                var trailing = variable.Identifier.TrailingTrivia;

                VariableDeclaratorSyntax newVariable = variable.WithIdentifier(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(leading, "i" + newName, trailing));
                var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(variable, newVariable);
                return new[] { CodeAction.Create("Add 'i'", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)) };

                 }
               }
          }
      }
  }

   return null;
 }
```

So, if I have a code like this one:

```
int variable = 0;
variable++;
```

I have a warning and a way to rename the declaration in one click. So the code change like that:

```
 int iVariable = 0;
 variable++;
```

But all the variable who had the name "variable" are not renamed! Visual Studio already have a CodeFix to rename the others variables who were called "variable", but it requires a second operation for the user.

Do you know how a code that I can implement who will rename all the variables directly?
If not, is there a way to call the CodeFix that Visual Studio offer?

Comment: (Comment about how much hungarian notation must die and rot in hell here). This question seems to deal with a similar issue (rename a const) so it might be useful to cross-reference it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312525/roslyn-rename-variable-const-in-majusucle (I personally don't believe it's close enough to be considered a duplicate though)

Comment: I know hungarian notation is not really good, but I have to do this job.. And about the "Rename a const", I've made this post and it is resolved now. The question is not the same, I'm not looking about how to rename but how to change multiple name at the same moment.

Comment: hungarian notation must die and rot in hell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for Roslyn's semantic rename engine.

Call [`Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync()`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Rename/Renamer.cs#122757488c14f307).

Comment: Works fine, thanks!
Note: it helps me: http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/05/solution-wide-rename-from-code-fix-provider-fix-async-method-naming.html